# React Native: How can i force a rerender to update my userIngredients Value?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

```html
  const [constructorHasRun, setConstructorHasRun] = useState(false);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  const [userIngredients, setUserIngredients] = useState([]);
  const [userRecipes, setUserRecipes] = useState([]);

  const user = useContext(AuthContext);

  const constructor = (userIngredients) => {
    if (constructorHasRun) return;
    getUserData()
    fetchRecipes(userIngredients)
    setConstructorHasRun(true);
  };


  constructor(userIngredients)


  async function getUserData() {
    var userData = await firebase.firestore().doc("ingredients/" + user.uid).get();
    var labels = await userData.data().ingredients.map(({ label }) => label)
    setUserIngredients(labels)
    setUserRecipes(userData.data().recipes)
  }
```

I want to update my userIngredients so it shows what i fetch but for the fetch i need a value in the userIngredients. setState() is async so i need another render to update the value. how can i force it ?

Comment: i think what you need is the `useEffect` hook

Comment: i had it before but i dont know how to use it right. on my other screen it works perfectly with useeffect but here it doesnt like i want so. how can i fix that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on my analysis of your code, you could either have the `fetchRecipes` call right after you get the data from firebase:

```
async function getUserData() {
  var userData = await firebase.firestore().doc("ingredients/" + user.uid).get();
  var labels = await userData.data().ingredients.map(({ label }) => label)
  setUserIngredients(labels)
  fetchRecipes(labels) // <-- moved this here
  setUserRecipes(userData.data().recipes)
}
```

or inside `useEffect` with `userIngredients` as dependency

```
useEffect(()=>{
  fetchRecipes(userIngredients)
}, [userIngredients])
```

Comment: so i can delete the constructor ?

Comment: that is unfortunate, perhaps the app specifications prevent the desired output. you can opt to attempt the 1st snippet

Comment: you're welcome. please consider [accepting my answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/399968)